# html font rejected by sanitizer (mozilla debugging)

Tags: html, css

The font was rejected by the sanitizer according to the message in the mozilla debugger. Other fonts have worked. HTML and css both validated, but font still doesn't work.

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: "parisr";
   src: url("parisr.woff") format("woff");
}

p
{
 font-family : "parisr";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>INDEX.HTML</title> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <style type="text/css"></style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts. Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule.</p>
  <div id="element1"></div>
  <div id="element2"></div>
  <div id="element3"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so with web fonts its not exactly because of css3, its because of security reasons fonts can be dangerous. some browsers like firefox will only allow the font from the domain eg, if your running a website that you can get to via 2 domains like mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com.au the fonts have to be served from those domains.

you do this like you have done above in your stylesheet, But make sure that the urls to the fonts are correct. the above css states that the url of the font is yourwebsite.com/parsir.woff if this is correct thats good but you might also require the other versions which you can do here https://www.web-font-generator.com/